# swrlapi: Invalid SWRL atom predicate 'Person'

Tags: owl, owl-api, turtle-rdf, swrl, swrlapi

When running a SWRL rule I get in swrlapi `Invalid SWRL atom predicate 'Person'`.

[Most help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223670/sqwrl-add-a-new-rule) suggests things like adding "Person" to the ontology. I think I've done that, but I want to be sure.

My ontology is the [turtle primer](https://www.w3.org/2007/OWL/wiki/PrimerExampleTurtle) with a few modifications:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix owl2: <http://www.w3.org/2006/12/owl2#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@base <http://example.com/owl/families#> .


###########################################
# Object properties
###########################################

<hasAncestor> rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ,
        owl:TransitiveProperty ,
        owl2:IrreflexiveProperty .

<hasChild> rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
    rdfs:subPropertyOf <hasAncestor> ;
    rdfs:domain <Person> ;
    rdfs:range <Person> ;
    owl:equivalentProperty <child> .

_:x0 rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty <hasGender> ;
    owl:hasValue <female> .
_:x1 rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:intersectionOf (<Person> _:x0) .
<hasDaughter> rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
    rdfs:range _:x1 ,
        <Person> ;
    rdfs:domain <Person> ;
    rdfs:subPropertyOf <hasChild> ;
    rdfs:domain <Parent> ;
    owl2:disjointObjectProperties <hasSon> .

<hasGender> rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .

<hasHusband> rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
    owl:inverseOf <hasWife> .

<hasSon> rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .
_:x3 rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty <hasGender> ;
    owl:hasValue <male> .
_:x4 rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:intersectionOf (<Person> _:x3) .
<hasSon> rdfs:range _:x4 ;
    rdfs:subPropertyOf <hasChild> ;
    rdfs:range <Person> ;
    rdfs:domain <Person> ,
        <Parent> .

<hasSpouse> rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ,
        owl:SymmetricProperty ,
        owl2:IrreflexiveProperty .

<hasWife> rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ,
        owl:InverseFunctionalProperty ,
        owl:FunctionalProperty ,
        owl2:AsymmetricProperty ,
        owl2:IrreflexiveProperty ;
    rdfs:domain <Person> ;
    rdfs:range <Person> ;
    rdfs:subPropertyOf <loves> ;
    rdfs:range <Woman> ;
    rdfs:subPropertyOf <hasSpouse> ;
    rdfs:domain <Man> .

<loves> rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
    rdfs:domain <Person> .

###########################################
# Data properties
###########################################

<hasAge> rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ,
        owl:FunctionalProperty ;
    rdfs:domain <Person> ;
    rdfs:range xsd:integer ;
    owl:equivalentProperty <age> .

###########################################
# Classes
###########################################

<Adult> rdf:type owl:Class .
_:x5 rdf:type owl2:DataRange ;
    owl2:onDataRange xsd:integer ;
    owl2:minInclusive "21"^^xsd:int .
_:x6 rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty <hasAge> ;
    owl:someValuesFrom _:x5 .
_:x7 rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:intersectionOf (<Person> _:x6) .
<Adult> owl:equivalentClass _:x7 ,
        <Grownup> .

<Child> rdf:type owl:Class .
_:x8 rdf:type owl2:DataRange ;
    owl2:onDataRange xsd:integer ;
    owl2:minInclusive "21"^^xsd:int .
_:x9 rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty <hasAge> ;
    owl:someValuesFrom _:x8 .
_:x10 rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:complementOf _:x9 .
_:x11 rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:intersectionOf (<Person> _:x10) .
<Child> owl:equivalentClass _:x11 .

<CivilMarriage> rdf:type owl:Class .

<Man> rdf:type owl:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf <Parent> .
_:x12 rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty <hasGender> ;
    owl:hasValue <male> .
_:x13 rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:intersectionOf (<Person> _:x12) .
<Man> owl:equivalentClass _:x13 .

<Marriage> rdf:type owl:Class .
_:x14 rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:unionOf (<CivilMarriage> <ReligiousMarriage>) .
<Marriage> owl:equivalentClass _:x14 .

<Narcissist> rdf:type owl:Class .
_:x15 rdf:type owl2:SelfRestriction ;
    owl:onProperty <loves> .
_:x16 rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:intersectionOf (_:x15 <Person>) .
<Narcissist> owl:equivalentClass _:x16 .

<Parent> rdf:type owl:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf <Parent> .
_:x17 rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty <hasChild> ;
    owl2:onClass <Person> ;
    owl:minCardinalityQ "1"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger .
_:x18 rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:intersectionOf (<Person> _:x17) .
<Parent> owl:equivalentClass _:x18 .

<Person> rdf:type owl:Class ;
    rdf:about "Person"^^xsd:string ;
    rdf:ID "Person"^^xsd:string ;
    rdfs:label "Person"^^xsd:string .
_:x19 rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:oneOf (<female> <male>) .
_:x20 rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty <hasGender> ;
    owl:allValuesFrom _:x19 .
_:x21 rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty <hasGender> ;
    owl:cardinality "1"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger .
_:x22 rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty <hasAge> ;
    owl:cardinality "1"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger .
_:x23 rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:intersectionOf (_:x20 _:x21 _:x22) .
<Person> rdfs:subClassOf _:x23 .

<ReligiousMarriage> rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:disjointWith <CivilMarriage> .

<Teenager> rdf:type owl:Class .
_:x24 rdf:type owl2:DataRange ;
    owl2:minInclusive "13"^^xsd:int ;
    owl2:maxExclusive "20"^^xsd:int ;
    owl2:onDataRange xsd:integer .
_:x25 rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty <hasAge> ;
    owl:someValuesFrom _:x24 .
_:x26 rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:intersectionOf (<Person> _:x25) .
<Teenager> owl:equivalentClass _:x26 .

<Woman> rdf:type owl:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf <Parent> .
_:x27 rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty <hasGender> ;
    owl:hasValue <female> .
_:x28 rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:intersectionOf (<Person> _:x27) .
<Woman> owl:equivalentClass _:x28 .

<YoungChild> rdf:type owl:Class .
_:x29 rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:unionOf (<Adult> <Teenager>) .
_:x30 rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:complementOf _:x29 .
_:x31 rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:intersectionOf (<Person> _:x30) .
<YoungChild> owl:equivalentClass _:x31 .

###########################################
# Individuals
###########################################

# Bill
_:x32 rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:complementOf <Narcissist> .
<Bill> rdf:type _:x32 ;
    <hasAge> "13"^^xsd:integer ;
    <hasGender> <male> .

# Ellen
_:x33 rdf:type owl2:DataRange ;
    owl2:minInclusive "15"^^xsd:int ;
    owl2:onDataRange xsd:integer ;
    owl2:maxInclusive "21"^^xsd:int .
_:x34 rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty <hasAge> ;
    owl:someValuesFrom _:x33 .
<Ellen> rdf:type _:x34 .

# Emily
_:x35 rdf:type owl2:DataRange ;
    owl:oneOf ("39"^^xsd:integer "49"^^xsd:integer) .
_:x36 rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty <hasAge> ;
    owl:someValuesFrom _:x35 .
<Emily> rdf:type _:x36 .

# Jack
_:x37 rdf:type owl2:NegativeDataPropertyAssertion ;
    rdf:subject <Jack> ;
    rdf:predicate <hasAge> ;
    rdf:object "53"^^xsd:integer .

# Jeff
_:x38 rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty <hasChild> ;
    owl:cardinality "2"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger .
<Jeff> rdf:type _:x38 ;
    <hasAge> "77"^^xsd:integer ;
    <hasChild> <Ellen> ;
    <hasWife> <Emily> ;
    <loves> <Jeff> ;
    <hasChild> <Jack> .

# John
<John> rdf:type <Person> ;
    <hasDaughter> <Susan> ;
    <hasGender> <male> ;
    <hasWife> <Mary> ;
    <hasSon> <Bill> ;
    <hasAge> "33"^^xsd:integer ;
    owl:sameAs <Jack> .

# Mary
<Mary> <hasAge> "31"^^xsd:integer ;
    <hasGender> <female> ;
    <hasSon> <Bill> ;
    <hasDaughter> <Susan> .

# Susan
<Susan> <hasAge> "8"^^xsd:integer ;
    <hasGender> <female> .

<female> owl:sameAs <feminine> .
<male> owl:sameAs <masculine> .

###########################################
# General axioms
###########################################

_:x39 rdf:type owl:AllDifferent;
    owl:distinctMembers (<John> <Mary> <Bill> <Susan>).

_:x40 rdf:type owl:AllDifferent;
    owl:distinctMembers (<Jeff> <Emily> <Jack> <Ellen> <Susan>) .

_:x41 rdf:type owl:AllDifferent;
    owl:distinctMembers (<male> <female>) .

# The following representation passes validation, but does not conform to the Turtle specification.
#(<hasSpouse> <hasSon>) rdfs:subPropertyOf <hasSon> .
_:x42 rdf:first <hasSon> ;
    rdf:rest rdf:nil .
_:x43 rdf:type rdf:List ;
    rdf:first <hasSpouse> ;
    rdf:rest _:x42 ;
    rdfs:subPropertyOf <hasSon> .

# The following representation passes validation, but does not conform to the Turtle specification.
#(<hasSpouse> <hasDaughter>) rdfs:subPropertyOf <hasDaughter> .
_:x44 rdf:first <hasDaughter> ;
    rdf:rest rdf:nil .
_:x45 rdf:type rdf:List ;
    rdf:first <hasSpouse> ;
    rdf:rest _:x44 ;
    rdfs:subPropertyOf <hasDaughter> .
```

I've done the following to try to fix it:

- I modified the `f` prefix to be the base prefix because I thought perhaps my Turtle rules would only recognize the base prefix in the ontology.
- Based on the comment on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47440589/swrl-rules-creation-in-owlapi-ontology) I added `manager.getOntologyFormat(ontology).asPrefixOWLOntologyFormat().setDefaultPrefix(base + "#")` after I define my ontology and before I add the rule engine.
- After reading [this](https://github.com/protegeproject/swrlapi/wiki/SWRLLanguageFAQ#does-swrl-support-the-use-of-annotation-values-to-refer-to-owl-entities) I added `rdf:about` `rdf:ID` and `rdfs:label` to the declaration of "Person"

Yet, I still get `Invalid SWRL atom predicate 'Person'` when I run the following command and infer:

```
SWRLRule rule = ruleEngine.createSWRLRule("IsSenior-Rule",
              "Person(?p) ^ hasAge(?p, ?age) ^ swrlb:greaterThan(?age, 60) -> Senior(?p)");
```

Comment: *"After reading this I added rdf:about rdf:ID and rdfs:label to the declaration of "Person""* -> that's clearly wrong, `rdf:about` and `rdf:ID` are mainly part of the RDF/XML serialization.

Comment: And your ontology is non-valid OWL, open it in Protege and you'll see a lot of parse errors.

Comment: Adding the rule would work if you'd add a class `Senior`. SWRL is for inference, it can't invent entities, i.e. all entities have to exist, i.e. at least their type must be declared. for example, `<Senior> a owl:Class .`